# UIApplication scheduledLocalNotifications is empty for past non-repeating notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have tried out the [3do app](http://www.cleversome.com/3do/index.php?tab=3do) which seems to be able to schedule non-repeating notifications and have specific notifications from notification center deleted. It works as this: when app is in background they are delivered in notification center, if you choose one of these notifications 3do will open and you have the option to tap "done", if you tap "done" that specific notification will be removed from the notification center. If you don't tap anything the notification will be left in notification center.

This is the problem I am myself having in one of my own applications, I can't understand how to delete an individual notification from the notification center. If the notification does not have a repeat interval then the `scheduledLocalNotifications` array of UIApplication will be empty so I can't cancel that specific notification and have it removed from the notification center. However if the notification has a repeat interval the scheduledLocalNotifications array will not be empty and I can delete this notification. But how can I deal with the scenario when the notifications are non-repeating?

Answer (score 10):

`scheduledLocalNotifications array will show as empty even if you have set local notifications`. Best way is to keep individual local notification objects. So that you can easily delete it.

When you set local Notification, save the object like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

NSString *userDefKey =  @"key";
NSData *dataEnc = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:localNotification];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataEnc forKey:userDefKey];
```

You should keep the key

When you want to delete a specific local notification

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:userDefKey]){

    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:userDefKey];
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotif];

}
```

Comment: I was curious about this approach and I tried it. I couldn't get it to work once the app is stop/relaunched. I'm guessing it works while running on the same session as the instances of the stored and the scheduled notifications are the same. Which is not the case once you restart the app.

Comment: It worked for me even after relaunching application..I remember I got a local notification after 4-5 months  from the time time of scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

Harikrishnan got me on right track, but I think there is actually an even better solution for this which is dead simple.

In the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` you will have a reference to the tapped notification in notification center. So you can just do:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    // This removes the notification from notification center
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: It's the simplest method If you want to clear it only after it got fired.

Comment: This method is called only when the notification is clicked or fired up while the app is on the foreground. Thanks @Harikrishnan for the answer, but I am unwilling to save instances. I am trying to find some correct way to do this with the provided methods by Apple. Let me know if you find the issue or the solution please!

Comment: That was a bug on iOS 5. So the only solution was storing instances in `NSUserDefaults`.So that we can directly access it. I don't know whether that bug is fixed in iOS 7.

Comment: I'm still encountering this bug in iOS 7. It happens only every now and then, but with thousands of active users, I get an empty scheduledLocalNotifications array every now and then.

Comment: Unfortunately in iOS 9 `scheduledLocalNotifications` is still empty after restarting the app (of course with a few pending notifications in future).